# Cannot delete unsigned char* array

Tags: c++, object, memory, heap-memory

In one of my objects, I create an unsigned character array member to store some image data:

```
    unsigned char* imageData;
```

and in the constructor I initialize it with new:

```
    MyObject::MyObject()
    {
        int imageSize = 6054400;
        imageData = new unsigned char[imageSize];
    }
```

imageData gets filled throughout the course of the loop.

This object (MyObject) won't get deleted until the very end of the loop, but I need imageData to be deleted midway through the loop.  So I just created this function:

```
    void MyObject::DeleteAllMembers
    {
        delete [] imageData;
    }
```

and I call it at the end of the loop:

```
    theObj.DeleteAllMembers();
```

The problem is that every time my program gets to the line of code:

```
    delete [] imageData;
```

it crashes, leaving this error message:

[image: error]

At this point I have no idea why this is happening.

Some of the things I've tried have been:

- initializing imageData with imageSize+1 instead of just imageSize
- moving the delete command to the destructor and manually deleting the object each run through the loop
- using delete imageData instead of delete [] imageData, even though I'm fairly sure that I need to use delete []
- I've tried doing `imageData = 0` after deleting it, unfortunately my program still crashes at the `delete [] imageData` line.
- I've tried using `memset(&imageData, 0, imageSize);`, but that gave me an access violation error.

Each time, the program still crashes at that same line.  I know someone is looking at my code thinking "You moron, all you have to do is ____________________."  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Sorry I said something incorrect.  I create this object each time at the beginning of the **loop** and it gets deleted at the end of the **loop**, I don't know why I said at the beginning and end of the program.

Comment: Are you obeying the rule of three? Is it the _same_ object in the loop, in which case a double-free will happen.

Comment: This statement: `theObj.DeleteAllMembers;` does **not** invoke `DeleteAllMembers`. You need `theObj.DeleteAllMembers()`.

Comment: Today I learned how bad I am at typing code without little red underlines to fix my mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to make a slight addition to prevent multiple deletion of the same pointer:

```
void MyObject::DeleteAllMembers
{
    delete [] imageData;
    imageData = 0; // <-- here
}
```

Comment: @AlokSave How do you know it?

Comment: The problem if your answer solves any is *Multiple deletion of the same dynamically pointer*, the solution you suggest hides the more basic fundamental underlying problem of why the same object be deleted twice.The solution is to find why that happens and not let it happen instead of hiding it.

Comment: @AlokSave A design problem and an implementation problem are two different things.

Comment: And what does that imply? Hiding design problems in implementation doesn't make much of an sense.

Comment: Neither does "much of an sense"

Answer (score 3):

Huh?

If you only allocate (with `new[]`) when the object is constructed, then you can't `delete[]` multiple times in a loop. You can only `delete[]` something once, passing the same pointer to `delete[]` again will fail.

Also, it doesn't make any sense: if you only *create* the array once at object-construction, then why would you need to *destroy* it more than once?

Answer (score 1):

Reset your buffer instead of deleting it in your loop if you need to re-use it.
For exemple with memset.

```
memset(&imageData, 0, imageSize);
```

Then, delete it when you no longer need it.

Comment: `memset` in C++? _No, thanks_. Also you didn't identify the problem.

Comment: And then, one day, `imageData` becomes something other than an object of a built-in type and _you don't notice_. I've seen this happen in real life, causing serious bugs in production code. Use `std::fill` instead, which is more type-aware. (At least you're not using C-style casts on the pointer, though.)

Comment: Just for the record, std::fill uses memset on char.
One day so much things could happen. And probably std::fill would not help too. However i agree with your comment but this is not the point i think.

Comment: It doesn't matter what `std::fill` does underneath.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but some points:

- If 'imageData' is a member of 'MyObject', then why is it's destruction being so explicitly managed from OUTSIDE 'MyObject'?
- If 'imageData' is destroyed in each iteration of "the loop", then it must be created again, before being used (and destroyed) again.
- Where is "the loop"?  If it's within a function that is a member of 'MyObject' or not changes the way you would approach managing 'imageData'
- You would only need to delete and reallocate the array every iteration of "the loop" if the size were changing.
- If 'imageData' ends up being created and destroyed within the scope of "the loop", why would it be a class member?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have
violated the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

The best solution to this problem is to avoid it altogether, for example by using `std::vector`. See "[Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)".

```
class MyObject 
{
  std::vector<unsigned char> imageData;
  ...
};

MyObject::MyObject() : imageData(6054400) {}

void MyObject::DeleteAllMembers
{
  imageData.resize(0);
}
```